# Wscript.run "No application is associated with the specified file for this operation"

Tags: vbscript, runtime-error, msgbox

I am trying to launch "GetPID.exe" and store the error code.
This is the .vbs code :

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile)
strFolder = strFolder & "\GetPID.exe"
Msgbox strFolder 
Dim temppid
temppid = WshShell.Run(strFolder , 0 , True)
```

However, at the last line, I get the following message:

> G:\test001.vbs(11, 1) (null): No application is associated with
>    the specified file for this operation.

The MsgBox echoes the correct path to the exe, so I am confused why is there the error.

Comment: `temppid = WshShell.Run( """" & strFolder & """", 0 , True)` is only a guess.

Comment: @JosefZ  It works, thanks

Comment: after a long time @JosefZ but I thought "avoid answering questions in comments"?

Answer (score 0):

*Avoid answering questions in comments*? I agree myself but [this thesis seems to be considered opinion-based here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312488/3439404). 

However, I agree yet another (outweighing) topical sentence: *a guess (a hunch) is not an answer*. In other words, I like generally applicable, **well-explained** solutions in **well-sourced** answers.

Unfortunately, due to lacking information on `GetPID.exe`, I can neither explain nor source this *forced* answer: as a matter of general principle, enclose the first parameter of `Run` method in a pair of double quotes.

You could use next syntax:

```
temppid = WshShell.Run( """" & strFolder & """", 0 , True)
```

Comment: not a forced answer, at least the question is not unanswered (: but a guess was answering the the question... what to do?... delete question? edit question? delete answer? edit answer?

Comment: its better if the answer is not forced: "avoid answering questions in comments" was only my opinion... so sorry...

Comment: @loadingnow you can give your own answer explaining origin of error; then, consider marking most helpful one as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important. I can delete my forced one on your demand.